# How can I read image metadata from binary blobs?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfimage

I have some images (in PNG and JPG format), stored as blobs in the database. I am retrieving them with a query and would like to take action by reading the metadata without writing the image to disk.

I am looking for the file type and image width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be abe to convert the data to a ColdFusion Image type using the `ImageNew` function [as documented here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-796f.html) (set the `source` to be the variable you pulled out of the query).

Once you have the image, you can use [the `ImageInfo` function](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7972.html) to retrieve image properties.

This will give you the width.  CF won't tell you the original file format, though--it might be easiest to look at magic numbers for that.  Wikipedia gives a good summary of what those are and what the values for jpeg and png are: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)